# Dicionarios dependentes de outros dicionarios

Tags: python

Boa tarde, estou com o seguinte problema, tenho de escrever uma função que receba um dicionario e uma matéria e imprimir todas as dependencias da matéria por exemplo :

```
dependencias_complicado = {
    'geometria_diferencial' : [ 'análise_complexa', 'topologia' ],
    'análise_complexa' : [ 'análise_real' ],
    'análise_real' : [ 'cálculo1' ]
}
```

o resultado seria :

```
cálculo1
análise_real
análise_complexa
topologia
```

no momento o código está assim :

```
def mostra_dependencias(dicionario, materia):
    for x in dicionario.get(materia):
      print(x)
```

o que me retorna somente : `[ 'analise_complexa', 'topologia' ]`

Comment: Por que o resultado seria `cálculo1`, `'análise_real`, `análise_complexa`, `topologia`? E qual é a entrada que geraria esta saída?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esse é um problema típico que depende de recursividade - ou seja,
a cada elemento a ser explorado, a chave com as dependencias devem ser
listadas de novo, e para cada nova dependencia, listar as dependencias da mesma.

Para evitar ciclos infinitos ou mesmo repetir dependencias que sirvam para mais de uma matéria, uma saída é ter um parâmetro opcional na busca recuriva que anote as dependências já visitadas - e assim, pule as que já foram
visitadas uma vez:

```
dependencias_complicado = {
    'geometria_diferencial' : [ 'análise_complexa', 'topologia' ],
    'análise_complexa' : [ 'análise_real' ],
    'análise_real' : [ 'cálculo1' ]
}

def lineariza_dependencias(chave, dados, javistas = None):
    if javistas is None:
        javistas = set()
    resultado = [chave]
    javistas.add(chave)
    for dependencia in dados.get(chave, []):
         if dependencia not in javistas:
             resultado += lineariza_dependencias(dependencia, dados, javistas)
    return resultado
```

E no terminal de Python:

```
In [116]: lineariza_dependencias("geometria_diferencial", dependencias_complicado)                                    
Out[116]: 
['geometria_diferencial',
 'análise_complexa',
 'análise_real',
 'cálculo1',
 'topologia']
```

Comment: Agradeço a ajuda

Answer (score 2):

```
for x in dependencias_complicado.values():
     for y in x:
             print(y)



análise_complexa
topologia
análise_real
cálculo1
```

Comment: Vlw pela ajuda parceiro